# Entropic Quine!

Tags: code-golf, quine, stateful

Your task is to write a program or function which:

- When run for the first time, outputs its source code.
- On subsequent executions, it should output what it output previously, but with one random character change (defined below). It does not have to be a uniformly random change, but every possible change should have a nonzero chance of occurring.

  After the first execution, your program will *not* necessarily be a quine anymore; the output will have changed (and the program is free to modify itself as well).

For example, if your quine was `ABCD`, repeatedly running it might print:

```
ABCD
A!CD
j!CD
j!CjD
```

### Specifications

- A character change is either:

  - The insertion of a random character,
  - The deletion of a random character, or
  - A replacement of a character with a new random character. Note that the new character is allowed to be the same as the one it replaces, in which case no change will be made.

  Of course, deleting or replacing a character from an empty string is not a valid change.
- Despite this being tagged [quine](/questions/tagged/quine), the rules against reading your source code do not apply.

You can use any character set as long as it includes the characters used in your source code.

Comment: What characters does *each character* refer to?

Comment: How often does this have to work? Clearly it can't be arbitrarily often or otherwise every possible program as longer or longer than the original one has to be a solution to the challenge.

Comment: So you run the _same_ program `ABCD` 4 times and it outputs 4 different outputs?

Comment: Also, the program can _change_ its own source code, but cannot _read_ its source code? How is that defined?

Comment: @user202729 The program modifies itself such that running it again produces a different output. All different outputs are relative to how the program was the first time.

Comment: I see that `j!CDJ` has 3 character changes (have string edit distance of 3) from the original program (`ABCD`).

Comment: @user202729 Correction: All different outputs are relative to the previous output, with the exception of the first output, which should be the program's source code at the time.

Comment: Can the character be added anywhere, or just at the end?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Anywhere.

Comment: Is the program only required to work the first iteration? If so posing the challenge as "write a program that prints itself with one random change" would be more clear

Comment: @dylnan No, it must work on subsequent iterations, where it outputs whatever it output last time with a random change. The program file itself is free to diverge arbitrarily from the output, as long as it produces the expected behavior on successive executions.

Comment: How many iterations does it have to work?

Comment: @dylnan Forever.

Comment: Is the source code changing? I'm not clear on whether the output of the first program will become the second program which then has to perform the same step as the first program

Comment: @dylnan The output of the first program becoming the second program etc. is inconsistent with the description, because you cannot then both have all possible random changes and have it keep working indefinitely.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I agree, I just think the challenge description is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @dylnan No, it doesn't. The challenge was initially downvoted and closed because people didn't understand that. Is there anything you think could make that more clear?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen The changes only are reflected in the output, not in the code. The program doesn't have to remain a quine, so the code and the output don't have to be the same after the first execution.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Do we get bonus points if we don't read our source code? I at least assumed that for the first output, it has to be a proper quine without reading the source. That's easy enough. Personally, I think reading your source code should be disallowed entirely. It makes it more challenging, but still easily possible.

Comment: I'd recommend changing 'addition of a character' to 'insertion', and maybe adding a reference to [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) being 1 between iterations (except when changing a character to itself)

Comment: Is no change a valid change?

Comment: @JoKing "Note that the new character is allowed to be the same as the one it replaces, in which case no change will be made."

Comment: So that's only for replacing? Can an empty string remain an empty string in the next iteration?

Comment: @JoKing No, it cannot.

Comment: Are we allowed to have a function instead of a program (in which case we store the last state in the outer program)? Otherwise you'll have to store the last source code with changed character either in a separated file or some OS settings in most languages.. (or modify the source code itself while still being able to run regardless of the change, which is close to impossible to do forever - since the program can potentially become empty..)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Not necessarily, because you can store the code in a string literal or something to ...

Comment: @EsolangingFruit In most languages not.. Executing a program will reset all those string variables.. I can execute a function multiple times with a class-level string. But executing a program resets to default in most programming languages.. It does in Java, C#, C, C++, and most other OO languages at least.. (Which was my main reason for asking for a function instead of a program, which is usually the default anyway.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen There are several solutions here that modify their source code. But you have a good point, so I'll allow functions as well.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>288 270 224 212 195 196 194 180 178</s></sup>168 bytes

```python
f=__file__
m=open(f).read()
x=m	
print(end=x)
h=hash
k=h(f)
n=k%2
a=h(m)%-~len(x)
x=x[:a]+(not(k%3)*x)*chr(k%127)+x[a+n:]
open(f,'w').write(m.replace("\t",";x=%r\t"%x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCoMwEAXP3c8Qglm1QvVQsORLrEjQSEQTQxpwe@mvpym9zYM3jHsHfdg2xkWM47LuahzBiMMpyxesvZIzRyBhLuD8agNXdhaEoIWWLw2b0OkGVmysAZmGQXb97Emmn0V9J4eS2yPwjbVYEBaT9olvzR1L6mVpuwH@sSo/c6xPvwbFTQq7XU6KZ8@QVdmDBPOJGCHG@AU)

After printing the file source code on the first iteration, we append an extra line to set x to the new source code, rather than m.

#### Explanation:

```python
f=__file__    #Open and read the source code
m=open(f).read()

x=m       #Set x to the source code for the first iteration
x="..."
...
x="..."   #Set x to the latest iteration
          #On the last iteration there's a tab character to mark progress
print(end=x)    #Print the previous iteration's text

#Modify the text
h=hash
k=h(f)            #Generate a random number to use
n=k%2             #Whether the character will be inserted or changed/deleted
a=h(m)%-~len(x) #The index of the change
                         #Add 1 to the range to append new characters, and to avoid mod by 0 in the case of an empty string
x=x[:a]+(not(k%3)*x)*chr(k%127)+x[a+n:]    #Make the change

open(f,'w').write(m.replace("\t",";x=%r\t"%x))   #Modify the source code, adding the new iteration of the source code
```

Assuming `hash` returns a uniformly random number, there is about 1/6 chance of inserting a new character, 1/6 chance of changing an existing character and 2/6 chance of deleting a character. What's the remaining 2/6 chance you ask? Why, it does nothing at all 2/6 of the time!

(Here's a validation program adapted from [mbomb007's answer's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165054/76162). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcoxDsMgDIXhPafwaIdUgoxIPQliYEjaRMggRCW65OrUqNn8P3/5W9@J194jPOHg/KlI054KsBToxdgJRp53LqsM0ASXwK8NI0kOEAb4b48rboyNlKGBoYg2Wo8zl4MrNGeDV8ip4klzo9nJ26vmgmLre9c/))

Comment: I think `f=__file__` would help in the first step too.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>779</s> 801 bytes

Though the challenge was edited to show that reading your source is allowed, I was already creating my solution without that. So, to show that it's possible, I finished it. No reading of the source file:

```python
s='s=%r;print s%%s\nfrom random import*;L=4;f=open(__file__,"wa"[L>5]);R=randint\nf.write("\\n".join((s%%s).split("\\n")[1:5:2]).replace("4",`map(ord,s%%s)`))\nif L>5:exec\'b=[];h=%%d\\nwhile~-h:b+=[h%%%%1000];h/=1000\\nwhile b:r,p,n=b[-3:];b=b[:-3];L=[L[:p]+L[p+1:],L[:p]+[r]+L[p+n:]][n<2if L else 1]\\nprint"".join(map(chr,L))\'%%1\n\nn=R(0,2);p=R(0,len(L if L>5else s%%s));r=R(0,255);f.write("%%03d"*3%%(n,p,r))';print s%s
from random import*;L=4;f=open(__file__,"wa"[L>5]);R=randint
f.write("\n".join((s%s).split("\n")[1:5:2]).replace("4",`map(ord,s%s)`))
if L>5:exec'b=[];h=%d\nwhile~-h:b+=[h%%1000];h/=1000\nwhile b:r,p,n=b[-3:];b=b[:-3];L=[L[:p]+L[p+1:],L[:p]+[r]+L[p+n:]][n<2if L else 1]\nprint"".join(map(chr,L))'%1

n=R(0,2);p=R(0,len(L if L>5else s%s));r=R(0,255);f.write("%03d"*3%(n,p,r))
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##tZHfboMgFMbvfQpjQpSWOv/UGxh7Aq96i6TTitHFIkGTbjd7dYfadl2WZkuWceMRPj6@c37qbag7GY1jT92eAk2UbuRg9wD0max0d7R1LkvzaY6q08OKpHRLKtopIb39vmpasd8j55Q7LH1KOCQ7OumNhbntn3QzCM/JMun4L10jPW/yhX6v2mZY9iELcYIjDn0tVJsfjHzroOdjrrxOl2jWP0OYyaayzQtYvIpD5haUcVJTAErjcapNivdNjYs1ZTUwKwyCwJw/0Km4KOwCa6SQpAXbxJiTwhR4E3PTEUsZVnydMrUOMUfLH9PLjsScM/kYTQFs0fbCDrnxnOfknPua4h5qjVKT1DXvZzKTku68AEWQqLlozcBSe@lidplbg0QvsiSB5DowAIK4dFYxAJ40kTWE7pVLb/2FivUJ5YbJDZJfEJmBWDc8rjjK7zC@ovgHEndBuCC0rJ8h3GVwRnAhYI3jBw) *(Note that this won't modify the source. You have to run it locally for that to work)*

To show that the transformations work, here is a [test program](https://tio.run/##tZHfboMgFMbvfQpjQpSWOv/UGxh7Aq96i6TTitHFIkGTbjd7dYfadl2WZkuWceMRPj6@c37qbag7GY1jT92eAk2UbuRg9wD0max0d7R1LkvzaY6q08OKpHRLKtopIb39vmpasd8j55Q7LH1KOCQ7OumNhbntn3QzCM/JMun4L10jPW/yhX6v2mZY9iELcYIjDn0tVJsfjHzroOdjrrxOl2jWP0OYyaayzQtYvIpD5haUcVJTAErjcapNivdNjYs1ZTUwKwyCwJw/0Km4KOwCa6SQpAXbxJiTwhR4E3PTEUsZVnydMrUOMUfLH9PLjsScM/kYTQFs0fbCDrnxnOfknPua4h5qjVKT1DXvZzKTku68AEWQqLlozcBSe@lidplbg0QvsiSB5DowAIK4dFYxAJ40kTWE7pVLb/2FivUJ5YbJDZJfEJmBWDc8rjjK7zC@ovgHEndBuCC0rJ8h3GVwRnAhYI3jBw) (currently set up to always pick `100` for `r`, and it prints the result for every combination of `n` and `p` for the initial list.)

---

#### Explanation:

```python
s='s=%r;print s%%s...';print s%s...
```

The first line is your classic quine, but a lot longer to account for what comes after.

```python
from random import*;L=4;f=open(__file__,"wa"[L>5]);R=randint
```

Import for random integers. `L` will become of list of ordinals of the source code, but initially it is an integer not used anywhere else in the source to allow for a string replacement. Open the file to write the new source. On later runs, it will open to append instead.

```python
f.write("\n".join((s%s).split("\n")[1:5:2]).replace("4",`map(ord,s%s)`))
```

Remove the first and third lines of code. Replace the `4` above with the list of ordinals.

```python
if L>5:exec'b=[];h=%d\nwhile~-h:b+=[h%%1000];h/=1000\nwhile b:r,p,n=b[-3:];b=b[:-3];L=[L[:p]+L[p+1:],L[:p]+[r]+L[p+n:]][n<2if L else 1]\nprint"".join(map(chr,L))'%1

n=R(0,2);p=R(0,len(L if L>5else s%s));r=R(0,255);f.write("%03d"*3%(n,p,r))
```

In pieces:

- `if L>5:` - Skips this line on first execution. Later, `L` will be a list, and this will run. I'll explain the `exec` last, because it's not run the first time.
- `n` - A random number 0-2. This determines which modification occurs (0 = insert, 1 = replace, 2 = delete).
- `p` - A random position in the list that the modification will occur at.
- `r` - A random number to insert or replace in the list
- `f.write("%03d"*3%(n,p,r))` - Append the 3 randoms to the end of the source file. Every run, this will be adding on to an integer that encodes all the changes to the initial source that have occurred.
- `exec'b=[];h=%d...'%1...` - Get the random numbers (found after `%1` on later runs), apply the changes to the list, and print.
- `while~-h:b+=[h%%1000];h/=1000` - Build a list of the randoms generated so far, accounting for the leading `1`, which prevents problems with leading zeros.
- `while b:r,p,n=b[-3:];b=b[:-3]` - Assign the randoms for this iteration.
- `L=[L[:p]+L[p+1:],L[:p]+[r]+L[p+n:]][n<2if L else 1]` - (0 = insert, 1 = replace, 2 = delete)
- `print"".join(map(chr,L))` - Print the modified source.

Comment: Does this sometimes delete a non-existent character from the end of the string? Since `p` can be the length of the string. Also, what's the behaviour with an empty string?

Comment: @JoKing I added a test program. Every possible character change can happen. It just shows that every position may be selected for an insert, replace, or delete, and that it handles an empty list. https://tio.run/##LYoxDsMgDEVnOAUjCAZgRO0NuIHloUOaRIocy6JDT08dpdt/733@ju2kOufhnm4n/gwf7PsUR0oup5Jqs6ZrlBetiz@CNVfmK//VQr6HWIIejeiz5KyLZafhoENjjB04lobpJpDbUEMEelScM/8A

Comment: I don't think that no change is valid, though I've asked the OP. The question does say `Of course, deleting or replacing a character from an empty string is not a valid change`

Comment: I've asked Esolanging Fruit, and they say that no change *is* valid, but not for an empty string.

Comment: @JoKing Should be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>205</s> 195 bytes

```python
s='print(end=x);h=hash;k=h(x);n=k%2;a=h(s)%-~len(x);x=x[:a]+(not(k%3)*x)*chr(k%127)+x[a+n:];open(__file__,"w").write("s=%r;x=%r;exec(s)"%(s,x))';x='s=%r;x=%r;x=x%%(s,x);exec(s)';x=x%(s,x);exec(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsIwEET/JRCSbatgexAM@ZJSQqiRlJa0JIGuF389roqIl2XnzTCz3bNfQ1dK0mKLU8jShatGUF57m7yatZekgp55qyyJBPzwWFx4UdTYX@xQy7BmOfMOKoRq9JH@U3uGGntbh8ug1o3yxtymxRnTsJ3BcY9TdpIlzSPV0HHoRipnXKYGAQRR8XNpiX@cb1C82R8q5Qk)

Wanted to try a version that doesn't read the source code. Turned out not a bad as I thought, and it's only 30 or so bytes behind the [version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165019/76162) that *does*. The explanation for how it works is mostly the same as the other answer, but it initialises x differently since it can't just read the source code.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 370 bytes

```java
String s;v->{if(s==null){s="String s;v->{if(s==null){s=%c%s%1$c;s=s.format(s,34,s);}else{int r=s.length();r*=Math.random();char c=127;c*=Math.random();s=s.substring(0,r)+(c%%3<2?c:%1$c%1$c)+s.substring(r+(c%%3>0?1:0));}}";s=s.format(s,34,s);}else{int r=s.length();r*=Math.random();char c=127;c*=Math.random();s=s.substring(0,r)+(c%3<2?c:"")+s.substring(r+(c%3>0?1:0));}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##vZLfSsMwFMbv9xSHYiGxa21VEBcz8QEUQfBGvMiydIu2qeSkExl99pm2Y8w/24WoF@0h55yc/L58eRILET9Nn1eyEIhwLbRZDgC0ccrmQiq4aZcAi0pPQZL7Niwo87lm4H93zmozA2S@5egIboV1UOXg5gomb07FsqqN8303YICvFvF4qXOCnJu6KOgSebAZ8LUWyhDD7EAy5JjklS2FIzg8OR0iZY0qUC09JVhfLJSZuTmhzB7ya@HmiRVmWpU@IefCguTZ8RmTn2vtWKwn2BGQdGhpRGQYnlwcX8pRe3D70Wi7yfYd4/QyG6XUYzTB/9L1cEHwDdY21Yq15rzUk0JLQCecD52DpfeX9Hf@8AiC9ua2rkMJHIx67RakcxjA6yKtDM1TBlGkL7KMwXoTQJmYRJLOLrZO3b2hU2VS1S558Ye4wpDgKvdvCYJIRwH08sALNzNFkI6CfVvLBPeV17XuIW6znntYHcdjH@gu1N3jdkvI0vSjANzg74X/gvdXfMP01wj/7Ap/yNgMmtU7)

#### Explanation:

```java
String s;               // Class-level String variable to store the modifying source code
v->{                    // Method without parameter nor return-type
  if(s==null){          //  If this is the first execution of this function:
    s="String s;v->{if(s==null){s=%c%s%1$c;s=s.format(s,34,s);}else{int r=s.length();r*=Math.random();char c=127;c*=Math.random();s=s.substring(0,r)+(c%%3<2?c:%1$c%1$c)+s.substring(r+(c%%3>0?1:0));}}";
                        //   Set `s` to the unformatted source-code
    s=s.format(s,34,s);}//   And then to the formatted source-code
else{                   //  For any following executions of this function:
  int r=s.length();r*=Math.random();
                        //   Random index in range [0, length_of_modified_source_code)
  char c=127;c*=Math.random();
                        //   Random ASCII character in unicode range [0, 127)
  s=                    //   Replace the current String `s` with:
    s.substring(0,r)    //    The first [0, `r`) characters of the modified source code `s`
    +(c%3<2?            //    If the random option is 0 or 1:
           c:"")        //     Append the random character
        +s.substring(r  //    Append the rest of the modified source code `s`, but:
          +(c%3>0?      //     If the random option is 1 or 2:
             1:0));}}   //      Skip the first character of this second part
```

#### General explanation:

**[quine](/questions/tagged/quine)-part:**

- The String `s` contains the unformatted source code.
- `%s` is used to input this String into itself with the `s.format(...)`.
- `%c`, `%1$c` and the `34` are used to format the double-quotes.
- (`%%` is used to format the modulo-`%`).
- `s.format(s,34,s)` puts it all together.

[Here a basic Java quine program.](https://tio.run/##lcrBCkBAEADQX9lki0KJm3yCk6McprU0ZGlnbEm@ffkC5fzeDA7SeVi8R8PajqC0aC5iYFTCbTiIFdBELVs0U9dDfDmwgurgX5dKksxDVbUnsV6z7eBsfw@PESVFmVBc3Xfwqd4/)

**Challenge part:**

- `String s;` is the source code we'll modify on class-level.
- `int r=s.length();r*=Math.random();` is used to select a random index of the source code in the range `[0, length_of_modified_source_code)`.
- `char c=127;c*=Math.random();` is used to select a random ASCII character (including unprintables) in the unicode range `[0, 126]`.
- `c%3` is used to select a random option of either 0, 1 or 2. Option 0 will add the random character before index `r`; option 1 will replace the character at index `r` with the random character; and option 2 will remove the character at index `r`.